# MODX Revolution. Can not download package from Package Manager

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

When I try to download and install package, I get an empty window with "Failure" title, and download doesn't start. What's the problem?

Provider is default - http://rest.modx.com/extras/

Curl extension is enabled.

Comment: Any errors in apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

Package Management requires cURL or PHP Sockets.

If you use cURL, make sure that the core/packages/ directory is writable by PHP.

To get cURL (and Package Manager) working on localhost with XAMPP, you may also have to modify your firewall and add an exception for the C:\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll file. [[2]](http://bobsguides.com/errata-mtog.html)

Check the [Troubleshooting Package Management page](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/installing-a-package/troubleshooting-package-management) for more information.

Comment: cURL is enabled. core/packages/ directory is writable by PHP. HTML cache is disabled. I still get "Failure" error.

Comment: What do you see on ModX Error log? What version of ModX are you running and what type of installation (traditional/Advance)?